Running Flutter project from DropBox (Windows and MAC)
I am trying to open and run my Flutter project (through android studio) using both my windows PC and MAC. I put the folder in the Dropbox directory and tried to run it.
It still runs from my windows.
As for the MAC, it ran fine once but after the second time it is giving me the following error:
Error:

lib/main.dart:1:8: Error: Error when reading '/C:/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/material.dart': No such file or directory

Which is weird because it is looking in the "C:" drive for Flutter dart file.
Any suggestion what I am missing here?
I thought maybe the the DART and FLUTTER path are not set right in the SDK and environment variables but double checked them and they are fine. Also other projects open up and run fine.

Its probably hardcoded somewhere in the .idea/ folder (which android studio uses to store project settings). The standard way to collaborate on a code project across different computers would be to use a git hosting website (could be github, gitlab, azure devops, bitbucket, etc ...). This would avoid the problem because the .idea/ folder is listed in the .gitignore file which would prevent sharing these and other files.

Thanks. for the suggestion. I will migrate to github. I deleted .dart_tool folder and ran it again and worked.

That makes sense. Neither one of those folders is intended to be shared. If you look at the .gitignore file, none of the files and folders listed there are intended to be shared, sometimes for configuration reasons such as this.

well that makes a lot more sensenow. thanks

I deleted ".dart_tool" folder and fixed the issue.
But not sure if that's the best way to go about though.
